# Laravel hasmanythrough or mysql groupby

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I have three tables

**category**

```
id | category_name | created_at | updated_at
```

**profile**

```
id | category_id | profile_name | created_at | updated_at
```

**photos**

```
id | profile_id | photo_name | photo_path | photo_type | created_at | updated_at
```

Now i need to list photos by category and also only one photo from each profile by photo_type

I have tried using hasManyhrough but descending by created_at not working

```
public function categoryPhotos()
  {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(ProfilePhoto::class,Profile::class);


  }


 $response=Category::with(['categoryPhotos'=>function($query){
            $query->where('profile_photos.photo_type',2);
            $query->orderBy('profile_photos.created_at','ASC');

          $query->groupBy('profile_photos.profile_id');

        }])->whereHas('categoryPhotos')->get();
```

if its not possible via laravel relation then mysql query also fine for me.Thank you

Comment: *and also only one photo from each profile by photo_type* Random foto from a group or some definite (the latter by creation date, for example)?

Comment: by created_at desc and phototype=2

Comment: *I have tried using hasManyhrough **but descending by created_at not working*** Does ascending - works?

Comment: @Akina.asc is default behavior so it doesn't affect

Comment: I'd recommend to solve this task using pure SQL then look does it can be converted to Laravel syntax, or it must be executed as raw. If you'll accept this way then add tables DDLs and task description on this level. PS. *Now i need to list photos by category and also only one photo from each profile by photo_type* - looks like "I need the list of categories, and one photo per category which has the former `created_at` and `phototype=2`". Additionally - what if no photos with `phototype=2` (or at all) in some category?

Comment: @Akina.thanks for helping out.if no photos then category shouldn't show .i am not good at mysql queries.so i tried in relation.even i get mysql i can covnert ot laravel

Comment: 1) What is your MySQL version? 2) Is it possible that some profile has 2 or more photos with phototype=2 and the same created_at which is the latter?

Comment: 10.1.35-MariaDB and .its defintly possible has multiple photos .

Comment: *10.1.35-MariaDB* That is bad - CTEs and window functions are not available...

Comment: @Akina.np.any thanks a lot for finding out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solution (if I understand the task correctly) may be

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM category ca
JOIN profile pr ON ca.id = pr.category_id
JOIN photos ph ON pr.id = ph.profile_id
JOIN ( SELECT ph1.profile_id, MAX(ph1.id) id
       FROM photos ph1
       JOIN ( SELECT profile_id, MAX(created_at) created_at 
              FROM photos 
              WHERE phototype=2
              GROUP BY profile_id ) sq1 ON ph1.profile_id = sq1.profile_id
                                       AND ph1.created_at = sq1.created_at 
       WHERE ph1.phototype=2
       GROUP BY ph1.profile_id ) sq2  ON ph.id = sq2.id
```

Explanations.

Subquery `sq1` selects last `created_at` for each profile for photos with phototype=2.

Subquery `sq2` takes this result and gets maximal `id` for photos which's profile and datetime matched those obtained in `sq1` (if more than 1 photo matches the conditions, this subquery selects one of them).

```
FROM category ca
JOIN profile pr ON ca.id = pr.category_id
JOIN photos ph ON pr.id = ph.profile_id
```

collects all possible combined rows - for each category it gets all related profiles with all related photos. Then we join our subquery, which filters this total list and gets only one row for each (category, profile) pair with the photo matched our conditions (or, if none such photo, none pair is selected).

Test it in this pure SQL form (does it gives correct result? start from separate sq1 execution, check, if correct then execute sq2 and check again, and finally check the whole query). If it is correct then try to convert it to Laravel form.